# Highcharts-Export: Issue, starting phantom server not closed at tomcat shutdown

Tags: highcharts, phantomjs

The example given in this github link [Github-highcharts-export](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/exporting-server/java/highcharts-export) have some bug.
While starting the tomcat after deployment their one phatomjs server process is started while shutdown hook the process doesn't killed and also at each time of tomcat restarting the process created again and again. Because of that their is some memory leak arises. This is want to be fix in their project itself.

If anybody know fix for this, kindly reply back it may helpful to me.

Comment: Could you give us some information on your platform specifics? Are the external processes not closed on shutdown or on redeploy?

Comment: I am using following tools, 1) STS IDE, 2) project is build on maven and its an web application, 3) phantom version - phantomjs-1.9.1-windows.. I download the github project for the highcharts-export from the above mentioned link, done phantom path changes in the app-convert.properties file and do the maven-install for generating the jar. Then i added that jar to my project generate the war of my project and then deploy with the tomcat-6. After deployment i start the tomcat it start the phantom process and then i stop & start the tomcat again it will start the phantom server again and again.

Comment: +1. I am running into similar issue. Have you found a remedy for this?

Comment: in app-convert.properties'https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/blob/master/exporting-server/java/highcharts-export/highcharts-export-convert/src/main/resources/app-convert.properties' file make the below line "# number of phantomjs servers you can run in the pool.
poolSize = 1" set poolSize = 0 as default. and while starting the server make it as one and while stopping the server make it as zero again